# InDesign: how to remove everything between square brackets

Tags: adobe-indesign, batch-processing, indesign-scripting, javascript, grep

I have a script to find all textframes in a document, and do a regular expression to remove (if contains) all text inside square brackets.

For example the text frame might contain:

"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit [test] Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit [test2]"

i have written the following script to find all textframes content then replace them using regex, but only does 1 per text frame and doesnt apply to all

If i run the below script, it gets rid of [test] but not [test2]

```
var myFrames = app.activeDocument.textFrames;

for (var i = 0; i<myFrames.length; i++) {
   var myFrame = myFrames[i];
   var string = myFrame.contents;
   var string2 = string.replace(/ *\[[^\]]*]/, '');
   myFrame.contents = string2;
}
```

Comment: Im not too familiar with indesign which is why i thought a script would be the best idea, how do i use the GREP find/change to remove everything within square brackets? Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You don't need to script this, just

- hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> and switch to the 'GREP' tab
- type `\[[^]]*\]` in the 'Find what' field
- or type the same thing with an `\s?` added in front to also remove any preceding whitespace, otherwise you'll be left with double spaces. so that's `\s?\[[^]]*\]`
- make sure the 'Change to' field is empty
- click 'Change All'

[image]